# Parse SDK, installed facebook framework, GADCustomEventBanner error

Tags: xcode, parsing

I have installed the Facebook SDK framework to integrate with Parse,
however I am now getting an error that says that the following code can not be found:

```
 #import "GADCustomEventBanner.h"
```

the error is:

```
'GADCustomEventBanner.h' file not found
```

Does anyone know where I can find this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might have deleted the file. Just download the framework and add the files back in.

Oh and by the way, try using Cocoapods. It gets sooo much easier when you manage your controls and dependencies.

Comment: It might have been the framework you were using. Anyway its a ad platform from google.